# A/B test sample size formula confusion

Tags: hypothesis-testing, variance, sample-size, ab-test

I was trying to understand the math behind some commonly used calculators and formulas for A/B tests and it seems that there might be some variations. Ideally, I would like to understand how each of them is derived and under what assumptions.

$$\left(\frac{\Phi_{1-\alpha/2}^{-1}\sqrt{2\bar p(1-\bar p)}+\Phi_{1 -\beta}^{-1}\sqrt{p_1(1-p_1)+p_2(1-p_2)}}{|p_2-p_1|}\right)^2$$ where $$ \bar p = \frac{p_1 + p_2}{2}$$ as far as I understand.

This is the formula I found here, for example:
https://jeffshow.com/caculate-abtest-required-sample-size.html

It's in Chinese, but from what I read after using Google Translate, this is exactly that type of calculation.

Honestly speaking, I have no idea where this formula comes from.

In the general case, the formula for the sample size is:

$$n \ge 2 \Big(\frac{\Phi^{-1}(1-\alpha/2)+\Phi^{-1}(1-\beta)}{\Delta/\sigma}\Big)^2$$

Under the assumption of equal variances, we can calculate the pooled variance as:
$$\sigma_p=\sqrt{\dfrac{(n_1-1)s_1^2+(n_2-1)s^2_2}{n_1+n_2-2}}$$, which can be simplified given that $n_1 = n_2$ as $\sigma_p = \sqrt{\frac{p_1\cdot(1-p_1) + p_2 \cdot (1-p_2)}{2}}$.

Plugging that into the formula for the general case, we get:

$$n \geq \frac{p_1\cdot(1-p_1) + p_2 \cdot (1-p_2)}{(p_2-p_1)^2} \cdot (z_{\frac{\alpha}{2}} + z_{\beta})^2$$

The results, however, are not the same when using these two formulas. As far as I understand, the famous Evan Miller calculator is based on the first formula.

For $p_1=0.5$ and $p_2=0.6$, my formula gives $n=384.16$ whereas this [calculator](https://www.evanmiller.org/ab-testing/sample-size.html) reports $390$ as the answer.

Can you please clarify it a bit? I believe there might be some assumptions or, even worse, something really trivial I fail to take into consideration.

Thanks!

Comment: You were so close! :) (+1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Maths is correct; the interpretation of what is the baseline needs a bit adjusting to get back to the EM result.

When comparing two arbitrary proportion coming from equal sized population, indeed the base-line proportion is $\bar{p}$ is $\frac{p_1 + p_2}{2}$. When though making an A/B test the base-line proportion is $p_1$. As such if we use $\bar{p}=p_1$ then we can get the results in question:

```
p1 = 0.5
p2 = 0.6
delta = abs(p1-p2)
alpha_level = 0.05
beta_level = 0.80
z_alpha = qnorm(1.0-alpha_level/2)
z_beta = qnorm(beta_level)

sd1_ab = sqrt(2*p1*(1.0-p1))
sd2 = sqrt(p1*(1-p1)+p2*(1-p2))
((z_alpha * sd1_ab + z_beta * sd2) / abs(delta))^2 # 390.0778 as expected
```

Now, what you have done though is to correctly derive the calculations in Appendix I from Hsieh et al. (1998) *[A simple method of sample size calculation for linear and logistic regression](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/9699234/)* ([Free PDF by core.ac.uk](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/190015073.pdf)).

Your result is:

```
(z_alpha+z_beta)^2 * (1/((p2-p1)^2)) * (p1*(1-p1)+p2*(1-p2)) # 384.5951
```

matching exactly the normal approximation for a balanced design in Hsieh et al. (Eq. 7 in Appendix I):

```
beta_star = (p2-p1) / sqrt( (p1* (1-p1) + p2 *(1-p2) )/2)
# Eq. 7
(z_alpha+z_beta)^2 / (p1 * (1-p1) * beta_star^2 ) # 769.1902
```

or per arm:

```
(z_alpha+z_beta)^2 / (p1 * (1-p1) * beta_star^2 )*0.5 # 384.5951 # Hooray!!
```

But indeed this is still not 390... The reason is that the calculation in Hsieh et al. Eq. 7 (and the ones in the post) are based on normal approximation. When the covariate is a binary variable we can compare the event rates (i.e. binomial proportions) directly. (e.g. See Rosner *[Fundamentals of Biostatistics](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Fundamentals-Biostatistics-Bernard-Rosner/dp/130526892X)* (Eq. 10.13 in the 8th edition))

```
# Eq 9 in the Hsieh et al. (equivalent with FoB 8E, Eq. 10.13)
k = (1-p1)/p1
((1+k) * (z_alpha * sqrt(p1*(1-p1)*(k+1)/1) + # Note we use p1, not p
          z_beta * sqrt(p1*(1-p1) + p2 *(1-p2)/k))^2 / (p1-p2)^2) /2 # 390.0778
```

As seen, the observed difference is subtle. Finally, to reference how this last result is derived I would suggest to look in Whittemoore (1980) *[Sample Size for Logistic Regression with Small Response Probability](https://statistics.stanford.edu/research/sample-size-logistic-regression-small-response-probability)*, it is based on asymptotic covariance matrix of the maximum likelihood estimates from the binomial distribution and; it complements the Hsieh et al. paper perfectly.

Comment: This is the answer I have been looking for. Thank you very much! In general, I have noticed that hypothesis testing is becoming more and more popular as more companies have more data and want to perform A/B tests, but very few of them care about the mathematics under the hood. 

By the way, you mentioned the book __Fundamentals of Biostatistics__. Can you recommend it as a reference? I have read mixed reviews on Amazon, but it's often quoted in articles and blog posts. I skimmed through a few pages and it seems that it's just a collection of theorems and results, without proofs

Comment: No... It depends a lot on what is your work. If you are starting on A/B tests, probably Kohavi et al. [Trustworthy Online Controlled Experiments](https://doi.org/10.1017/9781108653985) is a great bet, Kohavi is a Sith lord when it comes to A/B tests. Personally, I have come across a few Biostats resources that I mix-and-match them for my responses. The only Biostats book I have read almost cover-to-cover is Vittinghoff et al. [Regression methods in Biostatistics](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9781461413523) which tells you a lot about the level of rigour I aim for from my main resource.

Comment: I have a copy of Kohavi's book, but my main concern is that it totally lacks all the derivations and details I would like to see. It looks more like a handy collection of formulas and guidelines so that you don't have to think about the technical aspect. Honestly, this approach makes me feel uncomfortable.

Comment: Hmm. I don't have a go-to reference for something like that. As you saw, even in my answer I was mostly based on papers rather than than a single book. Maybe do a new question here? Reference requests questions are valid. Do mention there which books you have already tried to people can have a good idea of where you are coming from.